# Converting C++ project to a DLL to use in C# application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, openfiledialog

I've been searching around for days for a custom .NET control that can select multiple files and multiple folders all at once.

The only one I have found to be exactly what i'm looking for is the one below, but it's written in C++.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28015/SelectDialog-A-Multiple-File-and-Folder-Select-Dia

Can anyone please tell me how I can get it to work in my C# application? Either as a DLL reference or just including the project in my current solution.

I tried to compile it as an unmanaged DLL and then do a DLLImport from my C# project but couldn't get it working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code is simply a wrapper for the `GetOpenFileName()`/`IFileDialog` APIs with some customizations thrown in. What is stopping you from using those APIs directly in your C# code and making the same customizations? If you have to go the DLL route, you need to explain exactly what is not working for you.

Comment: Can you show the DLLImport code you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own custom form using the Windows API Code Pack's ExplorerBrowser. It looks just like the OpenFileDialog but you can select multiple files and folders all at the same time.

I've not seen anyone do this yet so I might post an article somewhere about it later...

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky if the class doesn't have a C# wrapper already created for it.  Are you absolutely sure you need this C++ control - in my experience I'd avoid using something that goes outside the .Net library unless you absolutely must.  It's a pain :0

Have a look at this - it's quite a good instruction list:
[How to Marshal a C++ class](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm going to try re-writing the control in C# tonight as @remylebeau mentioned it shouldn't be too hard. I'll let you know how it goes.